# change tab bar item image in swift programatically

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I am working on an app in Xcode. I currently have three tabBarItems on my tab bar. I want the middle one to be a picture chosen by the user. I have the desired picture in a variable and i have the tabbar.swift set up to put the code in. I just need to set the image to the variables image with correct size (and make the picture appear as a circle) and the title name to a string. 
Any help in doing this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Include your code, what you have tried, and what problems you are facing.

Comment: self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].image = UIImage(named: "your image name")
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "your image name")

Comment: and both failed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this code.

```
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].image = UIImage(named: "your image name")
    // items![0] index of your tab bar item.items![0] means tabbar first item

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "your image name")
```

Comment: I tried using this code in my tabbar.swift file but it didnt do anything

Comment: sorry.was in vacation. you are using custom tabbar.swift ? It will work where you want to change the image with the reference of tabBarController.